# How do I add a 0 to my minutes and seconds?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a piece of code that needs to display the time everytime it's ran. Right now it shows the time as 10:1:1 when it needs to be 10:01:01.

**How can i add the 0 when my minutes or seconds are <10?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
  html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100; 
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 24px;
        background: #d70080; 
      }

    div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
</style>

</head>
 <body>
  <script type="application/javascript">

  function BroadSignPlay(){
  var dd2 = new Date();var hh = dd2.getHours();var mm = dd2.getMinutes();var ss = dd2.getSeconds();
  var data2 = "De tijd is nu: " + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
  document.getElementById( "DivBroadSignPlay" ).innerHTML =  data2;
  }

  if (top.location != location) {
  top.location.href = location.href;
  }
</script>
 <div id="DivBroadSignPlay"> </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `mm.padStart(2, '0')` and `ss.padStart(2, '0')` you may also need to convert to a string first `mm.toString().padStart(2, '0')`

Comment: You're fast! I'm working on my code writing abilities so I hope you don't mind me asking. Could you show me how I would go about putting your sollution in my sample?

Comment: We should update the other question with new APIs.

Comment: @FelixKling I have done so...

Comment: Note that padStart is  [not supported by IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pad-start-end).

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.prototype.padStart(2, '0')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart). To stringify the number to call `padStart` on it, either call `toString()` on it first, or use a template string:

```js
function showTime(){
  const date = new Date();
  const hh = date.getHours();
  const mm = date.getMinutes();
  const ss = date.getSeconds();
  const str = [hh, mm, ss].map(x => `${x}`.padStart(2, '0')).join(':');
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = str;
}

showTime();
setInterval(showTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: @Ramselaar, did that answer your question ?

Answer (score -1):

To get leading zeros you can use `"0" + string` and then use [String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) with a negative start value `-c` to get the last `c` characters.

```js
function BroadSignPlay(){
  var date = new Date();
  var hh = date.getHours();
  var mm = date.getMinutes();
  var ss = date.getSeconds();
  var arr = [];
  [hh,mm,ss].forEach(function(x){arr.push(getleadingZero(x))});
  
  document.getElementById('DivBroadSignPlay').innerHTML = "De tijd is nu " + arr.join(':');
}

function getleadingZero(v) {
  return ("0" + v).slice(-2);
}

setInterval(BroadSignPlay, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="DivBroadSignPlay"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Would be nice to explain why.